# Complete List of all Google APIs?

Tags: api

There are many very interesting Google APIs and time by time i find a new one accidentally (i.e. [Google Geo Code API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/), or [Google Elevation API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/elevation/)).

Where do i find a complete list of all Google APIs? I haven't found any.

**EDIT 2013/Sep/13:**
The links below seem outdated as they do not show a complete list anymore.
I found another list at 
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/
containing interesting things - but this one does not seem to be complete as well.

Any updated link is appreciated.

Comment: You can use their discovery api for that https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=discovery&_v=v1 :P

Comment: Thats what i didn't find using Google ;) - but its still not complete. It does not contain i.e. all Mapping APIs.

Comment: Yeah, the directory and discovery APIs only list the newer APIs that were built specifically with discovery in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This link shows http://code.google.com/more/

[Google Libraries API - Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html)

> The Google Libraries API is a content
>   distribution network and loading
>   architecture for the most popular,
>   open-source JavaScript libraries.
>   Using the google.load() method gives
>   your application high speed and global
>   access to a growing list of the most
>   popular, open-source JavaScript
>   libraries. You can also use 
>   tags to include the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply find a list of available APIs on [google](http://code.google.com/intl/en/more/) site

Edit : since this link died, the new one is on [developers.google.com](http://developers.google.com), more precisely at https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=google-web-components

Comment: this seems like the best answer here

Answer (score 1):

The best list I know is on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) in the APIs section Services tab (you might have to have a project created first)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the real answer to your question

http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Comment: Nope. The API explorer misses many APIs - for instance the vast majority of [Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find where Google list all the APIs myself by looking particularly for where "Google Charts" is listed and found this thread which to me look like a confirmation that the complete list is nowhere.

[This list](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site%3adevelopers.google.com&hl=en) is the most complete list I see so far as of 2014.

Comment: This looks good, but does not list any of the APIs i am using: Static maps (V2), Elevation, Geocoding. Even the JS Maps AI (V3) i can not find there. I Think that google should do a better job in finding its own services.

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR They're in maps API pages which list on the first page of the result just go to https://developers.google.com/maps/ you will see it in "Web Services" section.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/ is no longer a list. You need to search for keywords.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Now there is better list but at the time I wrote this answer those results is the most complete one. You don't need any keyword because the first page of each product ranked higher than other pages.